# Add Filterable Search in all pages in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Some may think it as duplicate question, but its not. I have searched and tried many wordpress plugins,but they are of no use. The issue is "Filterable Search" Must be shown in all pages including "Homepage" in the center as content not as sidebar widget.

**I want exactly like the below sample image.**
[image]

I have used "**Ultimate WP Query Search Filter**" wordpress plugin, But got the result like the below image.

[image]

Anyone knows how to tweak "ultimate WP Query Search Filter" wordpress plugin or any new plugin let me know.

Your help will be really helpful to me and to others as we don't often find wordpress themes with these features at all.

> PS: If you know any free wordpress theme providing this feature, Let
>   me know about this miracle. ;)

Comment: I also want to know this.